# Error with C# Web Application Settings SiteMaster.master file

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I inherited a project from previous developers who left no documentation, and left one solution with 6 different projects. It has a lot of issues, it is hosted in Azure but is not a proper Azure Cloud Service or Web Application like it should be. For that reason changes made in Visual Studio cannot be published to Azure, and it looks like the previous developers were using Notepad to make changes to the applications.

I am only concerned with 1 web application out of the 6 projects.

The solution is hosted in Team Services (TFS) But I when I get the web application out of TFS, Visual Studio refuses to recognize it, and the Debug option to open the web application in debug mode is not available for this project. I am not sure how the previous developers were testing this web application using Visual Studio.

So What I did was create an empty web application in visual studio that runs correctly, and I began adding all the files from the web application I want to test in Visual Studio. I was able to successfully add all the files for App_Code folder and get them to build correctly, however when adding the aspx files I encountered this error when trying to build the project, in a file called SiteMaster.master

```
The type 'Settings' exists in both 'WebApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0,     
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'App_Code.qayx6oel, 
Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

The web application is using a variable called WebRoot in the Settings, like Settings.WebRoot, to be used for the web root for the javascript include files, since the web application is using JQuery and other Javascript libraries. However this variable WebRoot is not defined in Web.Config file appsettings section, like I would expect it to be.

searching with Google and Bing I did not find any matches to this error. So now I am posting it here.

Comment: One possible reason for this error is that there are 2 aspx pages which are having the same name/namespace in their inherits= in the <@page language=......inherits=> line.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the `Settings` class in App_Code to something unique like `OtherSettings`.

Then look for places where `Settings` is being used, and determine which of those need to be changed to use `OtherSettings`.